# Concurrency doubts in Django

Tags: python, django, concurrency

I'm developing a website with Django 1.5.1 and I have two doubts regarding concurrence. Now I'm runing on the development server.

1. When multiple users access the website at the same time, by default, does Django run each request in a different execution thread? Or must it be configured in the webserver e.g. Apache?
2. Will I experience issues if more than a user is modifying the same object concurrently? If so, how do you solve this problem? Using locks?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Its webserver specific. If you configure it to run in different process, request will be handled in new process. If you configure to have threads it will be in threads.
2. Yes. Imagine case when, user1 is viewing/editing a object A (retrieved from DB). user2 deletes that object. And then user1 tries to save it. You need to handle such cases explicitly in your code.

   - Most likely the issues will be related to DB. So you can use transactions to help in some cases.
   - In some other cases, you can define strategy. E.g the case mentioned above, when user1 tries to save the object, and its not there in db you can just create one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 1) Which one should I use: threads or processes in a website with aprox 80.000 visitors/month? 2) I'm using short time operations, updating just one or few records at a time, so I think transactions won't be needed in this case. Calling `save` should insert or update the record automatically.

Comment: 1. Its very loaded question, which will require some benchmarking/performance evaluation. To start with you can use standard webservers apache/lhttpd with default settings. And then update the configuration if you find bottlenecks. 2. Is fine.

Comment: @Caumons: transaction is necessary whenever you need to update multiple records that must all go in or all rejected. If you're updating only a single model for each request, then you usually do can safely skip transactions. Transaction is also necessary when there is a possibility that there is another request running in parallel that is updating an overlapping set of records.

Comment: @LieRyan Thanks for your comment, I'll keep it simple and don't use transactions for the momment, as I'm not updating large sets of records and Django uses autocommit by default.

Comment: @Caumons: autocommit is easy to understand, but it does not guarantee consistency, in fact it's the worse setting for that. If you have low to medium traffic, it's often a good idea to enable `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` or wrap most views with `commit_on_success`.

Answer (score 0):

1) webserver specific.

2) Take a look at [django-concurrency](https://github.com/saxix/django-concurrency).  It handles concurrent editing using [optimistic concurrency control pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control).